# Mac OS X tiger not installing on iMac G5 late 2005

Tags: imac

I’ve tried pressing/holding down c,x,control,alt,command and everything, and it still hasn’t worked. I’ve tried downloading even the ISO of the disk that came with it, and it still hasn’t worked. I’ve been trying for two days, is there any solution to this?

Comment: Those Macs need Mac OS X 10.4.2 (8E102, 8E104). If your disk or image is of an earlier 10.4, it won't work. Of course, it's possible it could be hardware failure. Can you give more information about the state of the machine and what didn't work? When did it last boot; what exactly happens when you hold down C (or D?) to boot from the DVD drive.

Comment: It showed a prohibitory sign ( the circle with an x through it

Comment: And what does it say on the disk for the version or build number? You are my eyes! Tell me everything!!

Comment: Version:10.3.5 Disc version: 1.1 Disc serial: 2Z691-5215-A Copyright date:2004 Name:iMac G5 Mac OS X Install Disc 1

Comment: That's the wrong disk. That's MacOS 10.3 - Panther, for a 2004 iMac, not a Late 2005 iMac.

Comment: I tried tiger, and it didn’t work either.

Comment: What was the build/version of the Tiger disk? Did you burn it yourself, or was it genuine? Did the iMac ever boot? What's the status of the internal drive?

Comment: I only really have an iso, I got it from archive.org/macintosh garden, since I live in south australia, i can’t really get install discs from retail. I burnt it on the Mac I was trying to install to

Comment: It’s also really weird, it has a Mac OS 9 drive select menu.

Comment: So does the Mac currently boot to the hard drive? i.e can we rule out that the Mac is broken? What OS is it running? I can't remember, but you might be able to just start the installer from an app or installer package on the disk.

Comment: The Mac is running leopard, everything works pretty good, but being on 512 mb ram leopard is slow.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the medium you have inserted is not bootable by your computer. You can use an USB drive for the reinstallation of Mac OS 10.4 . However, if I recall right, iMac G5 is capable of running 10.5 Leopard as well. It doesn't really matter. I am gonna continue this answer with the assumption of you have a disk image of either 10.4 or 10.5, as well as your mac is currently working or you have access to another mac; since you have mentioned you downloaded the disk image in question itself.

**Preparation of installation drive:**

1. Find an USB drive, with 8gb or more storage.
2. Insert it into the USB port of your computer.
3. Open up Disk Utility.
4. Select your drive and go to erase section.
5. Select "OSX Extended (Journaled) as your disk format and hit erase. (This will delete everything on the thumb-drive, thus make sure that you don't have anything valuable within the USB drive.)
6. When it finishes, right click on mounted drive and select get info.
7. Go to "Sharing and Permissions" section of poped up window.
8. Click the lock and enter your password.
9. Uncheck the setting "Ignore ownership on this volume".

￼[image: Screenshot]

10. Click the lock again in order to save the change you have just made.
11. Mount the dmg file of the Mac OSX installation (you can copy from the installation disk or download it from internet.)
12. Open up the Disk Utility again, this time select the partition you have created in step 5.
13. Go to restore section.
14. Select mounted DMG file (not the file itself the mounted image) as the source.
15. Hit restore.

**Booting with the thumb-drive:**

1. Boot/Restart your iMac with "CMD+OPTION+O+F" keys pressed.
2. Type `devalias` and press enter.
3. On the bottom of response from the command in step 2 you will see a drive named `ud`.
4. In order to boot from your drive, type `boot ud:,\\:tbxi`
5. You should be able to boot from the USB drive.

**Installation of Mac OSX:**

1. You should be greeted with the welcome screen.
2. Proceed the installation by clicking continue.
3. Select your hard drive, and click options.
4. Select "Erase and install". Make sure the format is selected as "OSX Extended (Journaled)".
5. Click continue, and it should be installed.

Hope if helps, the process of creating USB drive of 10.4 , 10.5 etc. can be done via any other Mac. Steps are the same.

Ps: Sorry for lack of images during the process. I am using Mojave right now so your screen responses might vary. Only the get info screen is pretty much the same as the "kitten" era of Mac OSX.

Comment: It shows the prohibitory sign.

Comment: (The circle with an x in it)